# Including a definition by variable

Tags: puppet

I'm working on putting together some puppet scripts - I've got a list of services (probably about 20 or so) that need to be deployed in very similar fashions.

1. Stop existing service
2. Get package out of nexus
3. Unzip it into directory
4. Set configuration variables
5. Start service

The problem is #4. Each service has a slightly different configuration. I'd like to use augeas to set the configurations for each service, and it seemed to make sense to make a definition for each service's config, and then that definition loaded in the main service definition.

So, I've got something like the following:

```
definition service ($serviceName) {
    //stopping, wget, unzip

    config[downcase($serviceName)] { "${servicename}_config":
        serviceName => $serviceName
    }

    //start
}
```

Then, I've got (for example) in the config module's manifest folder "foo.pp"

```
definition config::foo {
    //set some stuff
}
```

This isn't working due to various rules that I'm sure I've broken but are unaware of. Is there a 'standard' way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code below. You can put all these in a `define` type with variables for service name `myserv`. I would suggest of using `templates` to set the configuration rather than `augeas`... easier to control.

```
exec { "stop_myserv" :
  command => "service stop myserv",
  path => "/path/to/command/service",
  refreshonly => true,
 }

exec { "get_pkg_from_nexus" :
  command => "/command/to/do/the/above && unzip to/dirctory",
  path => "/path/to/command",
  require => Exec["stop_myserv"],
}

file { "set_configuration" :
  path => "/etc/somewhere/file",
  content => template("modulename/file.erb"),
  mode => "999",
  group => "jiut",
  owner => "muit",
  require => Exec["get_pkg_from_nexus"],
}

service { "myserv" :
  ensure => running,
  subscribe => File["set_configuration"],
}
```